# Index out of range error AFTER button in Cell works?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I add a button into cell of a TableView. Tableview works successfully which shows all the data I want. After I clicked the button which was set into a cell, the code runs successfully, But after that, it tells the error that Index out of range
From my understanding, error tell there is no any element in array after I clicked the button 
Why does it happen?

** NOTE: the error appear on this line:

```
let followerid = ArrayFollowersID[indexPath.row]
```

Here my code

```
class FollowersVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, 
    UISearchBarDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var FollowersTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Searchbar: UISearchBar!
    var ref = Database.database().reference()
    var ArrFollowers = [NSDictionary?]()
    var FilterArrFollowers = [NSDictionary?]()
    var ArrayFollowersID : Array<String> = Array()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        Searchbar.delegate = self
         self.FollowersTableView.rowHeight = 67

        //  retrieve the followers users
        ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("follower").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            let followersID = String(snapshot.key)
            self.ArrayFollowersID.append(followersID)
            self.Searchbar.placeholder = "Search \(self.ArrayFollowersID.count) followers"

            self.ref.child("profile").child("\(followersID)").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
                    self.ArrFollowers.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)
                    self.FollowersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.ArrFollowers.count-1,section: 0)], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
            })
        })
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if Searchbar.text != "" {
                       return FilterArrFollowers.count
                   }
                   return self.ArrFollowers.count
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FollowersCell", for: indexPath) as! FollowersTableCell
            let follower : NSDictionary
            let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
            let followerid = ArrayFollowersID[indexPath.row]

       cell.followaction = {
   self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("following").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

               if snapshot.hasChild(followerid){
                   cell.Followbutton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                   cell.Followbutton.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for .normal)
                        self.ref.child("profile").child(userid!).child("following").child(followerid).setValue(nil)
                        self.ref.child("profile").child(followerid).child("follower").child(userid!).setValue(nil)
}
}
class FollowersTableCell: UITableViewCell{

    var followaction : (() -> ()) = {}

    @IBOutlet weak var Followbutton: UIButton!


    @IBAction func FollowButton(_ sender: Any) {
        followaction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfRows` method code

Comment: I just updated the whole code

Comment: You have an `if` condition in `numberOfRows` method but no condition in `cellForRow` method. It is wrong

Comment: @Harryng add the same check in `cellForRowAt` same as `numberOfRowsInSection` when retrieving data from `array`

Comment: @iOSDev I added, not working out

Comment: @Harryng Your code has lot of logical mistakes. `ArrayFollowersID` should contain same number of elements as the array you used in `numberOfRows` method.

Comment: @iOSDev I understand, I did fix like you said as ArrayFollowersID, it works but some problem with search result. I'm trying to search with ArrayFollowersID filter. Normally I code search witha Array as a NSDictionary, now it is String Array

Answer (score 0):

First check this condition in `cellForRow`

```
if indexpath.row < yourArrayList.count {
  // set your cell data
}
```

this condition will help you out from index out of range error

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: 
based on iOSDev mentioned, the problem is I coded the Array.count incorrect way that the code can not understand which Array that indexPath should reply on. 
I fixed the code based on Array as NSDictionairy, no more String Array